# Launch Google Maps from my app to show multiple markers based on longitude and latitude with different colored markers

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps, mobile-application

I am trying to show multiple markers in the Google Maps application from my app with longitude and latitude, and I am also trying to change the color of the marker based on the type of marker I have to show.

```
private fun launchMaps(ticketLocationDetails:List<TicketLocationDetails>){
    try {
        val random = Random
        for (item in ticketLocationDetails) {
            val color = generateRandomColor(random)
            colorList[item.meter_serial_no] = color
        }
        val customMapUrl = constructCustomMapUrl(ticketLocationDetails)

        // Launch Google Maps app with the custom map URL
        val mapIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=${customMapUrl}")
        val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapIntentUri)
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
        mapIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(mapIntent)
    }catch (e:Exception){
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"unable to launch google maps application",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun constructCustomMapUrl(ticketLocationDetails: List<TicketLocationDetails>): String {
    return if (ticketLocationDetails.isNotEmpty()) {
        val centerCoordinateItem = ticketLocationDetails[0]
        // Construct markers for each point
        val markers = ticketLocationDetails.mapIndexed { index, point ->
            "&markers=7Clabel:${index+1}%7C${point.latitude},${point.longitude}&label=${Uri.encode(point.meter_serial_no)}"
        }.joinToString("")

        // Construct the rest of the URL with parameters
        val center = "${centerCoordinateItem.latitude},${centerCoordinateItem.longitude}" // Example center coordinate
        val zoomLevel = 10
        "https://www.google.com/maps/@$center,$zoomLevel?${markers}"
    }else{
        ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to show a Google Maps with markers in different colors, generated dynamically from your code, you need to use the Google [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start).

This will give you a **static image** (available in a few [formats](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#ImageFormats)) and supports markers in any colors and 3 sizes:

[image: Google Maps Static API image showing 3 markers of different colors and sizes.]

Note URLs start with
maps.**googleapis**.com/maps/**api/staticmap**

The URL format you have in your code, with URLs that start with **[www.google.com/maps/@](http://www.google.com/maps/@)** will take you to the Google Maps *consumer application* (maps.google.com) which is not an API and does not support any of the parameters the Maps Static API supports.

If you really want to send your users to Google Maps, using a supported API that won't break your applications (unpredictably and with no notice at all), use instead the Google [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started) (again, no support for markers).

Comment: I used static api url for displaying markers in google map application from my app but its not working its launching google maps app but not showing points 

val markers = ticketLocationDetails.mapIndexed { index, point ->
                    "&markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C${point.latitude},${point.longitude}&label=${Uri.encode(point.meter_serial_no)}"
                }.joinToString("")
                val uriBuilder = "https://www.maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${center}&zoom=${zoomLevel}${markers}&key=${key}"

Comment: is Google map application will support to show multiple markers from other apps ?

Comment: No. Google Maps does not support multiple markers. And the Static Maps API is one that will return a static image, it will not launch the Google Maps app.